# How to merge keys in inner object with its parent (unnesting)

Tags: jq

This is an example input:

```json
{
  "key1": "value",      
  "key2": [
    {"key3": 5, "key4": "value1"},  
    {"key3": null, "key4": "value2"},  
    {"key3": 9, "key4": "value3"}
  ]
}
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "key1": "value",
  "value1": 5,
  "value2": null,
  "value3": 9
}
```

This was generated with the following Python code:

```py
new = {x['key4']: x['key3'] for x in old}
new['key1'] = old['key1']
```

I attempted to do this with jq, but this is far as I got:

```
[.[] | {k1: .key1, k2: .key2 | map({ (.key4): .key3}) | add}]
```

Which gives me

```json
{
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": {
    "value1": 5,
    "value2": null,
    "value3": 9
  }
}
```

I'd say that what's missing is how to "merge" keys in the object with the top-level. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your input JSON fixed to take keys/values in double-quotes, your expression could be written as

```
[ {key1}, (.key2[] | { (.key4): .key3} ) ] | add
```